# How to reference a file in the source dir from any Java code?

Tags: java

Suppose I had a directory containing resource files stored somewhere within the "src" source directory, containing things like templates, config files, etc.

I'm aware that from a Servlet I can access files by name like:

`File file = new File(ServletContact.getResource("some/namespace/filename.txt").getPath());`

And from a non-Servlet I can do:

`File file = new File(Object.class.getResource("some/namespace/filename.txt").getPath());`

But the problem is that I have code that needs to access these resource files and can be run independent of the runtime environment.  e.g. Some code uses templates from within a servlet (under Tomcat 7).  Other code runs as a Quartz background job and works with templates.  If I try the `Object.class.getResource()` method in a Tomcat servlet, it returns null.

How can I access resources files in a safe way regardless of runtime environment, app engine, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read file from **classpath** you can use:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path/to/resource");
```

Also there is simple and useful **Spring** utility `ClassPathResource` class:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("path/to/resource");
```

Comment: Calling getClassLoader() on a class within my application was the trick.  Using Object wasn't good enough.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use any class (e.g. domain class) from your project, use getClassLoader() or getContextClassloader() and provide the path to your resource. Should work.